# How to digitally sign a pdf using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, certificate, itext, digital-signature

How do i sign a pdf using iText ? I'am going through this [LINK](http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html)  but didn't understand about my_private_key.pfx. Do i really need a certificate for digital signature ? Please clarify me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'am also having the same problem. Can anyone clarify us ? Please

Comment: @rahul, you need to close your 'other question'.

Comment: Why do we need a certificate? Do all users need the certificate who wants to sign pdfs on my website or only i will buy the certificate and make them enable signing on my website. I am little confused to implement this.

Comment: @RohitArora The certificate certifies that a specific key pair (a private and a public key) belongs to you. Without a certificate anyone could add a digital signature to a PDF and state it was you signed it.

Comment: The private key is kept private and is used to sign the document. The public key and the certificate are added to the PDF. The PDF viewer can then verify that it was indeed you who created the PDF.

Answer (score 6):

hope this ll help you

```
public class JPdfSign {

private static PrivateKey privateKey;

private static Certificate[] certificateChain;

private static ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("strings");

private static String PRODUCTNAME = bundle.getString("productname");

private static String VERSION = bundle.getString("version");

private static String JAR_FILENAME = bundle.getString("jar-filename");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    // System.out.println("arg[" + i + "] :" + args[i]);
    // }
    if (args.length < 2)
        showUsage();

    try {

        String pkcs12FileName = args[0].trim();
        String pdfInputFileName = args[1];
        String pdfOutputFileName = args[2];
        boolean usePKCS12 = !(pkcs12FileName.equals("-PKCS11"));

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("pdfInputFileName : " + pdfInputFileName);
        System.out.println("pdfOutputFileName: " + pdfOutputFileName);

        if (usePKCS12)
            readPrivateKeyFromPKCS12(pkcs12FileName);
        else
            readPrivateKeyFromPKCS11();

        PdfReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new PdfReader(pdfInputFileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err
                    .println("An unknown error accoured while opening the input PDF file: \""
                            + pdfInputFileName + "\"");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(pdfOutputFileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err
                    .println("An unknown error accoured while opening the output PDF file: \""
                            + pdfOutputFileName + "\"");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        PdfStamper stp = null;
        try {
            stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0');
            PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
            sap.setCrypto(privateKey, certificateChain, null,
                    PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
            // sap.setReason("I'm the author");
            // sap.setLocation("Lisbon");
            // sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), 1,
            // null);
            stp.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err
                    .println("An unknown error accoured while signing the PDF file:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    } catch (KeyStoreException kse) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while initializing the KeyStore instance:");
        kse.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}

private static void readPrivateKeyFromPKCS11() throws KeyStoreException {
    // Initialize PKCS#11 provider from config file
    String configFileName = getConfigFilePath("pkcs11.cfg");

    Provider p = null;
    try {
        p = new SunPKCS11(configFileName);
        Security.addProvider(p);
    } catch (ProviderException e) {
        System.err
                .println("Unable to load PKCS#11 provider with config file: "
                        + configFileName);
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    String pkcs11PIN = "000000";
    System.out.print("Please enter the smartcard pin: ");
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        pkcs11PIN = in.readLine();
        // System.out.println(pkcs11PIN);
        // System.out.println(pkcs11PIN.length());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while reading the PIN:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    KeyStore ks = null;
    try {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs11", p);
        ks.load(null, pkcs11PIN.toCharArray());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while reading the PKCS#11 smartcard:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while reading the PKCS#11 smartcard:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while reading the PKCS#11 smartcard:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    String alias = "";
    try {
        alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
        privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pkcs11PIN.toCharArray());
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while retrieving the private key:");
        System.err
                .println("The selected PKCS#12 file does not contain any private keys.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while retrieving the private key:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while retrieving the private key:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    certificateChain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
}

protected static void readPrivateKeyFromPKCS12(String pkcs12FileName)
        throws KeyStoreException {
    String pkcs12Password = "";
    KeyStore ks = null;
    System.out.print("Please enter the password for \"" + pkcs12FileName
            + "\": ");
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        pkcs12Password = in.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while reading the password:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    try {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(pkcs12FileName), pkcs12Password
                .toCharArray());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while reading the PKCS#12 file:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while reading the PKCS#12 file:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to open the PKCS#12 keystore file \""
                + pkcs12FileName + "\":");
        System.err
                .println("The file does not exists or missing read permission.");
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while reading the PKCS#12 file:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    String alias = "";
    try {
        alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
        privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pkcs12Password
                .toCharArray());
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while retrieving the private key:");
        System.err
                .println("The selected PKCS#12 file does not contain any private keys.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while retrieving the private key:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        System.err
                .println("An unknown error accoured while retrieving the private key:");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    certificateChain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
}

protected static String getConfigFilePath(String configFilename) {
    CodeSource source = JPdfSign.class.getProtectionDomain()
            .getCodeSource();
    URL url = source.getLocation();

    String jarPath = URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile());
    File f = new File(jarPath);
    try {
        jarPath = f.getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    if (!f.isDirectory()) {
        f = new File(jarPath);
        jarPath = f.getParent();
    }
    System.out.println(jarPath);
    if (jarPath.length() > 0) {
        return jarPath + File.separator + configFilename;
    } else
        return configFilename;
}

public static void showUsage() {
    System.out.println("jPdfSign v" + VERSION
            + " by Jan Peter Stotz - jpstotz@gmx.de\n");
    System.out.println(PRODUCTNAME + " usage:");
    System.out
            .println("\nFor using a PKCS#12 (.p12) file as signature certificate and private key source:");
    System.out.print("\tjava -jar " + JAR_FILENAME);
    System.out
            .println(" pkcs12FileName pdfInputFileName pdfOutputFileName");
    System.out
            .println("\nFor using a PKCS#11 smartcard as signature certificate and private key source:");
    System.out.print("\tjava -jar" + JAR_FILENAME);
    System.out.println(" -PKCS11 pdfInputFileName pdfOutputFileName");
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: because of the line sap.setCrypto(privateKey, certificateChain, null,
                    PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED); it seems you are using a version of itext prior to 5.3 (maybe 2.1). These versions are long deprecated.

Comment: @Broken_Window are there any examples with newer versions? The only ones that I managed to find contains deprecated methods like 'setCrypto'.

Comment: I have same problem as @BekaBot