# can not sign pdf using java with co sign get 90030103 error

Tags: java

please help me.
I am trying sign pdf using cosign. hear is part of my code

```
try {  
            initializeKeyStore();
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostnameVerifier());
            final DSS dss = new DSS(wsdlURL, new QName("http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/", "DSS")); 
            final SignRequest req = createSignRequest(pdfFile, signFieldName, userName, password);
            signRes = dss.getDSSSoap().dssSign(req);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DssException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

but I am getting "90030103" error.

Can anyone provide me some simple tutorial, where I can find how sign PDF.

Comment: have you seen this link? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666266/how-to-digitally-sign-a-pdf-using-itext

Comment: Thank You, I am already fix my problem. I have some syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on http://www.berthou.com/us/2007/11/28/sign-a-pdf-document/
I hope it will be useful for your purpose.